# Is there any method to make different browsers to run from same CSS code

Tags: css

I have created a CSS file which runs pretty well on Chrome , when it comes to Opera and Safary it website style behaves strangely. Each browsers need some different type of CSS based on its version and platform.

Is there any conversion method that can convert CSS file to universal so that whatever runs well in Chrome must run in Safari

Comment: Sometimes there are actual functional differences. I don't think there is a generic answer for that. But often it's about Vendor prefixes, for example `-webkit-`, for experimental features that didn't make it to the standard yet. 
A starting point to deal with those is the article: [How to deal with vendor prefixes - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create specific rules for different browser:

source: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/create-browser-specific-css

```
/* Chrome version 29 and above */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
selector{ property:value; }
}

/* Chrome version 22-28 */
@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
selector { -chrome-:only (;
property:value;
);}
}

/* Chrome, Safari, and also the Edge Browser and Firefox */
@media and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
selector { property:value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Should I depend more on Bootstrap so that it may adjust automatically based on browsers ?

Comment: that could be a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically add CSS vendor prefixes by using autoprefixer (a postCSS plugin) https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer. Alternatively, use this online prefixer: https://autoprefixer.github.io/